# Calling function in a namespace without qualification

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

Looking at the source code of `boost::polygon`, I have seen many applications of the following theme:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace B {

struct A {
  void foo() const { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

void bar(const A &a) { a.foo(); }
void baz() { std::cout << "baz" << std::endl; }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  B::A a;
  bar(a);
  B::baz(); // simply calling baz() does not work

  return 0;
}
```

How is it that `bar(a)` can be called without extra qualifications? I would have expected that only `B::bar(a)` would compile.

When the function does not have an argument inside the namespace, this does not occur.

Comment: Look up "ADL" (Argument Dependent Lookup) aka "Koenig lookup".

Comment: ADL reference on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: Thanks, that was quick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to ISO C++14 standard, at §3.4.2:

> When the postfix-expression in a function call is an unqualified-id, **other namespaces not considered during the usual unqualified lookup may be searched, and in those namespaces, namespace-scope friend function or function template declarations not otherwise visible may be found**. These modifications to the search **depend on the types of the arguments** (and for template template arguments, the namespace of the template argument).

And following:

> For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the types of the function arguments..
>
> If `T` is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. **Its associated namespaces are the innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes**.

Actually you can even prevent this from happening by enclosing the function name:

```
(bar)(a); // doens't compile
```

while

```
(B::bar)(a); // does compile
```

Mind also that this applies only to the innermost namespace, which means that in the following situation you need to qualify the namespace:

```
namespace B {
   namespace C {
     struct A {};
   }

   void bar(const C::A& a) { ... }
}
```